# How to convert TypeScript discriminated union into an object

Tags: typescript

Say, I have a structure like

```
//Modified from https://blog.parametricstudios.com/posts/pattern-matching-custom-data-types/.

enum RouteEnum 
{
  Home = "/",
  Todos = "/todos",
  Todo = "/todos/:id",
  NotFound = "*"
}

class HomeLocation
{
  readonly route = RouteEnum.Home;
  
  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Home](this);
  }
}

// A list of all Todo item links, when one is linked the next route is in TodoLocation.
class TodosLocation
{
  readonly route = RouteEnum.Todos;

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Todos](this);
  }
}

// A single Todo location.
class TodoLocation 
{
  readonly route = RouteEnum.Todo;

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Todo](this);
  }
}


class NotFoundLocation 
{
  readonly route = RouteEnum.NotFound;

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.NotFound](this);
  }
}

type NewLocation = HomeLocation | TodosLocation | TodoLocation | NotFoundLocation;

type LocationMatcher<Out> =
{
  [RouteEnum.Home]: (route: HomeLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.Todos]: (route: TodosLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.Todo]: (route: TodoLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: (route: NotFoundLocation) => Out;
};
```

would it be possible to turn `NewLocation` into a structure like

```
// The matching order here is from the the first to latter.
const routes = {
  '/': HomeLocation,
  '/todos': TodosLocation,
  '/todos/:id': TodoLocation,
  '/*': NotFoundLocation
}
```

In case it matters, the larger reason for this question is that I'm thinking to do route matching over this structure but naturally there needs to be a way to turn URLs to those `*Location` classes.

One example could be using something like https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/js-router (or a similar approach that more readily fits this structure). This particular library for instance operates on a structure like that `routes` example. I think that even without using this specific library knowing how to enumerate over the discriminated union and create a new type would be good to know information.

The goal would be to have the parsed parameters as strongly typed. This is manual, of course, but they need to matched first from their corresponding route  in the `*Location` classes, in one way or another. One option is to have a callback function per `*Location` class that takes the input from a matched route.

**Edit**
I wrote a StackBlitz to illustrate my pondering better. It's at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hl6drb?file=index.ts.

Comment: Are `'/article/*` and `Todo` typos?  Should they be `'*'` and `TodoLocation` respectively?

Comment: Ah, yes. I copied that last part from the referenced `js-router` while writing this and thinking how to bridge this "enumerate over discriminated union" gap in my n00b TS knowledge. I edit the text, just a sec.

Comment: Also the question title confuses me.  I don't see an array of tuples mentioned anywhere in the body of the question.  Or any arrays or any tuples at all, for that matter.

Comment: It must be my n00b TS skills. I mean the `const routes = {` part that is an object now that I think of it. I think also, related to your quick answer that my problem is to transform the `NewLocation` into a runtime structure like that `const routes = {` so I could readily use the `js-router` library without writing strings more than once or maybe taking that library code and refactoring it to directly work on that structure.

Comment: So by "runtime structure" you mean you want the *type* `NewLocation` to be transformed into something that emits JavaScript?  The answer is "you can't do that"; it's against the TS design goals (specifically, it is [non-goal #5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals)). TS's type system is meant to describe, not emit JS.  You can do the opposite though; write your runtime structure and then generate a type for it.

Comment: Yes... I was thinking that maybe it's possible to collect metadata and generate something from there. I'm more knowledgeable on this and some other things, looking at the syntax.

I'm tempted to think about removing the `const` from the enum and thinking to rework the discriminated union, but my skills aren't strong enough and I probably end up to dead end like now. Would writing a runtime structure help with turning routes to strongly typed classes?

Comment: I meant to write
> Yes... I was thinking that maybe it's possible to collect metadata and generate something from there. Though now that you wrote tht sample, I'm more knowledgeable on this and some other things, looking at the syntax and your comments (learning is good)...

In the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to programmatically generate an object type where the keys come from the `route` property of the `NewLocation` union members and where the values are constructors for the corresponding element of `NewLocation`, then you can do it like this:

```
type RoutesType = { 
  [K in NewLocation['route']]: new () => Extract<NewLocation, { route: K }> 
};
```

That evaluates to the equivalent of

```
type RoutesType = {
    "/": new () => HomeLocation;
    "/todos": new () => TodosLocation;
    "/todos/:id": new () => TodoLocation;
    "*": new () => NotFoundLocation;
}
```

and you can then annotate the `routes` variable as that type:

```
const routes: RoutesType = {
  '/': HomeLocation,
  '/todos': TodosLocation,
  '/todos/:id': TodoLocation,
  '*': NotFoundLocation
}
```

note that this is the same thing as

```
const routes: RoutesType = {
  [RouteEnum.Home]: HomeLocation,
  [RouteEnum.Todos]: TodosLocation,
  [RouteEnum.Todo]: TodoLocation,
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: NotFoundLocation
}
```

so you can write that either way if you want.

Does that work for you?  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9mALsAouaBvAsAKClACTgmCgF4oAiAekoBpd8AVOAEzgGdyrrE3P6jKC3bcafdh2oAuAJatBeKADk4iAGIIQrMQCpKuAL65cAYwA2AQw5ciJADJxTlxLLggo2JQCdgl9iDmAJ5Q3gjI3PBIqOgAdHbAANwmShAupgAWADwA8kgAfAAUaYiZwN7SUI7Oru4AsukZ5bkFAJSVeYieQvi+iGDeHiVl3gDaUchokPHEwAC6hYgZshytyUrGOJtmVjbC-BzVLm4eXr1+AcGh4aQUEzHTIpzrQsPZnUVv5ZVHtSANpSa3haiHy7SgnW6SnO-UGUC+Y3uUwgsSeHAWSxWayEm22OAs1i4T1+Jyh5387iuYWikRuyNR-BeqUaIM+jW+VScx3q7OBH3BkLO+FCwFhQ154zpcSeGOWq3W+FxKR2hJUak0YG0JPcZJFFMCIWpETuUumqg0WlYTPwb1ZxV5Py5fwBI1ZAqQuphA3FgPKkui9PNGu0sqxCqgSpwuEQQQADqRlMAAO7ajwUBKpqAAH32kkzOeJTtJOaDltTTJj8c5NROLqBrPIQiF+H9kziCTmlUKRuAlQzRfcrXI+QhSHDLaR0oOnag3ZulTRqaHZBHnXHUFbDxRMq7PYX-CXw9HiHXm8D6stM7n0Uqpc1rEPK+P4cMTJSldI9w4TDjt11owAaSgWQPETFMBxAUYAHIeyguYZxAZNZ2XEcUAAD0QbxLFMRAsjA1M6E8a4bygIDDHyIwmWoXQoGjX9YBub96IoZseEoSpEKTZCj37Gt3HXcQDnYqBOO4p9FwggTeAOGR5GE0TChQ3M4HLHoqH0DikMUo87y1SSjFwXRqFoqN8XcDguh7DhKi-H8qxYoQz3bWYZ147kQAYJQnMead9zzCDPInU1t34GdCz4jzHMnM0L3vGddIfCCDNMoA)

---

There's also something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAMiYBDKBLcBhANkiECmEMAvDANoCwAUDDMDnjABIgC2+Cya4MA3tbVoAnfEgAm4LAE8YQkAFco+EjABEAelUBuAYNYpgACwA8AeUUA+ABT6oR-EIBc8RCnRgAsgcMOzlgJTO5rD8NILC+FDyQmAwtvZCZFCGqBAAdHKK+AC6Vsmp-jphtAC+uiUANLr0uEQAKiASEJxuPKHhIuKSMplKKhpQjSAQqrq08SbB1hMOzi3cnt6+U4EwwXxjgiJRMXFLifnpvTl5KRCFm2VhldUM9UPz7hvFsqISYNKyCn2kA0MQ6kcqDEoxeEz8UGm+zmrgWXjsPiEEIsq3W7XCrx2sRmBzOGW+J0OFxeV3KVTCNUYADkQFAAGIKMBiR5tTadd6fY79ABUoPC4KmNmhLi47nhCWRqMUzwxmOi2P2STxx1yRKK4SupWo2RguDo4GgRWoUCkAAdlCywNhaoQVCbzSAAGYi1pWu6EMhgeSsABGDmyRXtyip+AA7paVABJSBQJBgYD4Opm-DGS3WvCECyB5MwABKBIAqkIsERSCHw7D3GQAOTHasB405-NZCBJ80qdFkADSMFQsWbSiLJeyzgAogAPKBCJDAKCpyuYd0QCowMBhmBWNJbpBCADmEGccak-hIFj4Xyyzh7JQs1BK2fblvFiLMZ9InZ7fbzheLEBHG+OMdJ2nWdjHLS0V14C8lCvGAbxPYgz1MO9qGoUAY2g21SDTJcMnwMR5ATKwrCEZcYCwYAELPEiIE9dcKKsfx8SyHVSAo3UiCPFdSP8SCSg478WzbfBiVQqggA) which is the closest I can get to going from values to types here...

Comment: Let I check, I started a Stackblitz just now. :)

Comment: To come back at this, I think in https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hl6drb?file=index.ts writing like `const routeDefinitions2 = {
  '/': HomeLocation,
  '/todos': TodosLocation,
  '/todos/:id': TodoLocation,
  '*': NotFoundLocation
}` almost could work. Though then it's writing the routes two times first in the enum and then in the route definition (I think I could supply a function as the second paramter that then could `new` or something one of those classes).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what you mean by "writing two times" since you've been writing, e.g.,  `RouteEnum.Home` all over the place.  Oh, let me make a quick change to the answer (which doesn't really change the types at all) and see if that feels different to you:

Comment: I try to do pattern matching on TS and I'm still learning. I've tried all sorts of things and https://blog.parametricstudios.com/posts/pattern-matching-custom-data-types/ got be closest (that I understand something/enough). Let I see that one, it looks that latest should work. I understand (now that you wrote it) that it's not possible to take `type NewLocation` and enumerate it to create a similar structure, so the alternatie is to write the routes twice (RouteEnum+routes) for the matching or somehow alter the types. This is better than writing plain strings twice, I think. But let I check...

Comment: This seems to work, I edited the Stackblitz link too. I think we're good to go here. This was much appreciated, I learned a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Take a quick look at the playground link I added to the bottom of this answer (the link says "this") for a possible way to go from your classes to your types... I basically got rid of the enum entirely.  Maybe it'll give you some ideas.  Good luck again!

Comment: Hmm, this may even be easier to understand. Closer to C# or F#, feels like. Much appreciated!

Comment: I add her for other readers that one difference between first and second version is that in the second version the `*Location` constructors are called before a match is made and the function in `.page` is explicitly called.