# How to create a real class instance from type definition (using new () => Extract<T>)?

Tags: typescript

In the following the use case is matching compile time route definitions with runtime URL paths using a regular expression and then doing pattern matching over the structure. The compile time routes are defined using a discriminated union and as far I understand, the problems stems on how to create the runtime pattern matchable instances from the compile time discriminated union instances.

The question is basically how to provide runtime types of these compile time discriminated unions? But this requires more context, so see following and the question rewritten more specifically after that.

The following code snippet is also present in https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hl6drb?file=index.ts and as such is live code that can be inspected (see console logs), debugged and tweaked. The code is also replicated here and specifically in the end there is a simple test case and Visual Studio Code (or Stackblitz) type observations. In `package.json` one extra packaged to do pattern matching is  `"@captaincodeman/router": "1.0.1"` which can also be found at https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/js-router. I do not think this is central to this question but provided here for convenience.

I have written my observation and problem also in the code and highlight it here:

```
// However, the error message here tells that howToGetObjectInstanceHere is undefined.
// It is interesting the console log print is
// Route 2. Page: function TodoLocation() {
// this.route = RouteEnum.Todo;
// console.log("TodoLocation constructor called.");
// }, params: 41237
// and RouteType values (right-hand side) are new () => *Location.
// If this the TS function constructor syntax as in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_functions.htm?
```

It appears to me the problem is at

```
type RoutesType = { 
  [K in NewLocation['route']]: new () => Extract<NewLocation, { route: K }> 
};
```

in which the compile type is brought to runtime type.

I understand this line transforms a class constructor call that would return `this` (I maybe be wrong that TS/JS constructor returns a `this` pointer) into an ordinary function call with the same name as the constructor.

This would mean there there will not be a runtime instance of this object that would be needed after matching the pattern.

**Question:** Is it possible to transform the code so it creates and actual instance of `TodoLocation` in this case? Which would mean any `*Location` using this pattern match.

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
import createMatcher from '@captaincodeman/router';

// Taking a cue from https://blog.parametricstudios.com/posts/pattern-matching-custom-data-types/.

// More about constant enums at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html.
const enum RouteEnum
{
  Home = "/",
  Todos = "/todos",
  Todo = "/todos/:id",
  NotFound = "*"
}

class HomeLocation
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.Home;

  public constructor()
  {
    console.log("HomeLocation constructor called.");
  }
  
  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Home](this);
  }
}

class TodosLocation
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.Todos;

  public constructor()
  {
    console.log("TodosLocation constructor called.");
  }

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Todos](this);
  }
}

class TodoLocation 
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.Todo;

  constructor()
  {
    console.log("TodoLocation constructor called.");
  }

  public instanceFunction()
  {
    console.log("TodoLocation instanceFunction called.");
  }

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Todo](this);
  }
}

class NotFoundLocation 
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.NotFound;

  constructor()
  {
    console.log("NotFoundLocation constructor called.");
  }

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.NotFound](this);
  }
}


type NewLocation = HomeLocation | TodosLocation | TodoLocation | NotFoundLocation;

type LocationMatcher<Out> =
{
  [RouteEnum.Home]: (route: HomeLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.Todos]: (route: TodosLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.Todo]: (route: TodoLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: (route: NotFoundLocation) => Out;
};

const testUrl1 = new URL("https://example.com/");
const testUrl2 = new URL("https://example.com/todos");
const testUrl3 = new URL("https://example.com/todos/3");

type RoutesType = { 
  [K in NewLocation['route']]: new () => Extract<NewLocation, { route: K }> 
};

const routeDefinitions1 = {
  '/': "abc1",
  '/todos': "abc2",
  '/todos/:id': "abc3",
  '/article/*': "abc4"
}

const routeMatcher1 = createMatcher(routeDefinitions1);
const route1 = routeMatcher1('/todos/41237');
console.log("Route 1. Page: " + route1.page + ", params: " + route1.params.id);

const routeDefinitions2: RoutesType = {
  [RouteEnum.Home]: HomeLocation,
  [RouteEnum.Todos]: TodosLocation,
  [RouteEnum.Todo]: TodoLocation,
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: NotFoundLocation
}

const routeMatcher2 = createMatcher(routeDefinitions2);
let route2 = routeMatcher2('/todos/41237');
console.log("Route 2. Page: " + route2.page + ", params: " + route2.params.id);

// This calls the constructor of TodosLocation class. How to get the instance?
const howToGetObjectInstanceHere = route2.page();

// However, the error message here tells that howToGetObjectInstanceHere is undefined.
// It is interesting the console log print is
// Route 2. Page: function TodoLocation() {
// this.route = RouteEnum.Todo;
// console.log("TodoLocation constructor called.");
// }, params: 41237
// and RouteType values (right-hand side) are new () => *Location.
// If this the TS function constructor syntax as in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_functions.htm?
howToGetObjectInstanceHere.instanceFunction();
```

For more context, this is a follow-up to my question at [How to convert TypeScript discriminated union into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550935/how-to-convert-typescript-discriminated-union-into-an-object) superbly helped by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz). He wrote also another version of the same code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAMiYBDKBLcBhANkiECmEMAvDANoCwAUDDMDnjABIgC2+Cya4MA3tbVoAnfEgAm4LAE8YQkAFco+EjABEAelUBuAYNYpgACwA8AeUUA+ABT6oR-EIBc8RCnRgAsgcMOzlgJTO5rD8NILC+FDyQmAwtvZCZFCGqBAAdHKK+AC6Vsmp-jphtAC+uiUANLr0uEQAKiASEJxuPKHhIuKSMplKKhpQjSAQqrq08SbB1hMOzi3cnt6+U4EwwXxjgiJRMXFLifnpvTl5KRCFm2VhldUM9UPz7hvFsqISYNKyCn2kA0MQ6kcqDEoxeEz8UGm+zmrgWXjsPiEEIsq3W7XCrx2sRmBzOGW+J0OFxeV3KVTCNUYADkQFAAGIKMBiR5tTadd6fY79ABUoPC4KmNmhLi47nhCWRqMUzwxmOi2P2STxx1yRKK4SupWo2RguDo4GgRWoUCkAAdlCywNhaoQVCbzSAAGYi1pWu6EMhgeSsABGDmyRXtyip+AA7paVABJSBQJBgYD4Opm-DGS3WvCECyB5MwABKBIAqkIsERSCHw7D3GQAOTHasB405-NZCBJ80qdFkADSMFQsWbSiLJeyzgAogAPKBCJDAKCpyuYd0QCowMBhmBWNJbpBCADmEGccak-hIFj4Xyyzh7JQs1BK2fblvFiLMZ9InZ7fbzheLEBHG+OMdJ2nWdjHLS0V14C8lCvGAbxPYgz1MO9qGoUAY2g21SDTJcMnwMR5ATKwrCEZcYCwYAELPEiIE9dcKKsfx8SyHVSAo3UiCPFdSP8SCSg478WzbfBiVQqggA) in case this makes the problem easier to understand or change.

There is a slight difference between these two that in the first the `*Location` class constructor is called when the function constructor is called and in the second the constructor is called earlier (in `LocationClasses.reduce` step).

Comment: This is way too complicated to see what is going on. Can you make the example code smaller? Where are the `new` keyword?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, but it's in `[K in NewLocation['route']]: new () => Extract<NewLocation, { route: K }> ` and see the call in `route2.page();` that calls the constructor of `TodoLocation`. The logging in https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hl6drb?file=index.ts should help too. Just so you, and others, now, it's past one o'clock at night here and I need to keel over to bed now.

Comment: [Don't signal your edits in text.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text)

Comment: Tomorrow then, but I thing we will need to know more about createMatcher too

Comment: Due to time zone diffences I comment here already now that: @RobertHarvey Acknowledged. Akxe That is a fair point, it is https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/js-router that creates it. I think I should write this question to be more self-contained and bring more context from the previous question.

Comment: I edited the question so its hopefully more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have simplified the question a bit by removing 2 of 4 routes, and replaced the imported function by TS declare.

```
type Routes = { [pattern: string]: any };
type Result = {
    page: any
    params: { [key: string]: any }
} | null;
type Matcher = (url: string) => Result;
declare const createMatcher: (routes: Routes) => Matcher;

// Taking a cue from https://blog.parametricstudios.com/posts/pattern-matching-custom-data-types/.

// More about constant enums at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html.
const enum RouteEnum
{
  Home = "/",
  NotFound = "*"
}

class HomeLocation
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.Home;

  public constructor()
  {
    console.log("HomeLocation constructor called.");
  }
  
  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.Home](this);
  }
}

class NotFoundLocation 
{
  public readonly route = RouteEnum.NotFound;

  constructor()
  {
    console.log("NotFoundLocation constructor called.");
  }

  match<Out>(matcher: LocationMatcher<Out>): Out
  {
    return matcher[RouteEnum.NotFound](this);
  }
}


type NewLocation = HomeLocation | NotFoundLocation;

type LocationMatcher<Out> =
{
  [RouteEnum.Home]: (route: HomeLocation) => Out;
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: (route: NotFoundLocation) => Out;
};

type RoutesType = { 
  [K in NewLocation['route']]: new () => Extract<NewLocation, { route: K }> 
};

const routeDefinitions1 = {
  '/': "abc1",
  '/article/*': "abc4"
}

const routeMatcher1 = createMatcher(routeDefinitions1);
const route1 = routeMatcher1('/todos/41237');
console.log("Route 1. Page: " + route1.page + ", params: " + route1.params.id);

const routeDefinitions2: RoutesType = {
  [RouteEnum.Home]: HomeLocation,
  [RouteEnum.NotFound]: NotFoundLocation
}

const routeMatcher2 = createMatcher(routeDefinitions2);
let route2 = routeMatcher2('/todos/41237');
console.log("Route 2. Page: " + route2.page + ", params: " + route2.params.id);

// The `createMatcher` function should return just a lookup for the URL.
const howToGetObjectInstanceHere = new route2.page();

howToGetObjectInstanceHere.instanceFunction();
```

The point was, that you were calling the construction, but not as new-able, but as a function.

---

As I found out after writing my own generic there is [a pull request](https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/js-router/pull/4) that does the same. He can make his function return better type, one derivated from the input.

```
type Routes<T> = { [pattern: string]: T };
type Result<T> = {
    page: T
    params: { [key: string]: any }
} | null;
type Matcher<T> = (url: string) => Result<T>;
declare function createMatcher<T> (routes: Routes<T>): Matcher<T>;
```

If you were to replace the imported function with this snippet, you would see the typescript error: `Value of type '(new () => HomeLocation) | (new () => NotFoundLocation)' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)`

Comment: You are right on the solution and the refactoring. It didn't occur for me to use that `new` keyword since somehow I assumed calling the function would be enough since the `console.log` printed (or I remember completely wrong). This prompoted me to look later at pitfalls between TS -> JS and other JS engine things, but it's for later questions then. :)

Comment: An update for you. The author of the library updated his function to be type safe.